# Сборка Qt5 из исходников на Linux

Tags: mysql, qt, qt5, компиляция

Имеется Ubuntu 16.10 x64, необходимо создать статическую сборку Qt5 с MySQL для этой ОС.

На данный момент в поиске решения. Под Windows получилось сделать сборку, а в Linux какие то проблемы.

Qt 5.6 скачан через онлайн-установщик с официального сайта.

Comment: @maint ошибки разные, т.к. я по частям пытаюсь проблему выявить. По поводу необходимости сборки, тут с вами не соглашусь,  статическая линковка без пересборки не работает. А без неё возникают сложности при переносе приложения, по крайней мере так оно с Windows 7.

Comment: 1) Нужно собирать из Qt исходников, мне кажется. 2) Этот комментарий будет полезен: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37559267/static-build-of-qt-with-built-in-mysql-library#comment62656154_37574566

Answer (score 1):

Есть куча руководств как пересобрать  Qt статически. 
Офсайт советует добавить опцию -static к ./configure. http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/linux-deployment.html

Но лично мой совет попробовать вместо этого сделать

```
ldd ./application
```

Что покажет список зависимостей. Скопировать их в папку с приложением и попробовать переносить так. Можно даже сделать гламурный инсталлер на Qt installer framework. 
А если вы статическим прилинкуете Qt библиотеки к исполняемому файлу. То по условиям GPL будете обязаны отдать искодники проги любому кому отдаёте эту самую прогу. Потом могут быть проблемы.